# Some blocks not updating untill clear the cache

Tags: blocks

My Recent Forum Topics and Recent Contents blocks are not showing new contents untill I clear the cache from Performance section.

I've added these standard blocks to my homepage but they don't work.

Comment: Do you have block cache turn on? (config/development/performance). Are these blocks created with views? If so do you have the views caching?

Comment: Is this for anonymous users only?

Comment: Hello,

block cacheing disabled, yes, I've created via Views module.

Unfortunatly this is for all user.

Comment: Have u tried to **set caching to none** under **others** under **advanced** in your **view display**. @Can